# PHP PDO Data_length always returns "0"

Tags: php, pdo, datalength

Well, I'm just trying the following for around two hours now and I can't get it to work. The following code will always return "0". Please, can anyone see where is the problem. This should work as a charm. And in PhpMyAdmin, when I run the statement it works correctly.

Actually, this is a copy/pasted code from another question here on SO which was accepted as a working answer. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487673/php-pdo-retreive-mysql-db-size).

**EDIT:**
No errors are thrown using:
`error_reporting(-1);` and 
`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

**UPDATE:**
Definitely, I'm getting only the first row from the query where the `Data_lenght` is "0". I've tested also `fetchAll`, and also trying to access the `Data_length` index while fetching. No luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
try {
    error_reporting(-1);
    $host_name  = "my_hsot";
    $database   = "my_db";
    $user_name  = "my_user";
    $password   = "my_pwd";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name;dbname=$database", $user_name, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $conn->query('SHOW TABLE STATUS');
    $dbSize = 0;
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbSize = $row["Data_length"];
    $decimals = 2;  
    $mbytes = round($dbSize/(1024*1024),$decimals);
    echo $dbSize . "\n" . $row["Data_length"];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO always returns "0" because `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` returns only the first row from the query, and the index of `Data_length` there is "0", as it could be any other value.